# Dynamically generating the value of ng-options in an AngularJS component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm maintaining an old AngularJS (1.6) project. At one point, I have a component that displays a list (select input). The field options that are loaded dynamically, using ng-options.

I would like to generate the ng-options value (`.. as .. for .. in .. track by ..`).

That string needs to be generated within the component's controller, using `$onInit` to get the bindings. Yes, because all the field names that will be used in the ng-options string value will actually come from bindings.

So in my controller, I'd like to do something like that :

```
this.$onInit = function() {
    this.options_string = (this.val1 ? 'obj[' + this.val1 + ']' : 'obj') + ' as ' + (this.val2 ? 'obj[' + this.val2 + ']' : 'obj') + ' for obj in $ctrl.options' + (this.trackby ? ' track by obj[' + this.trackby + ']' : '');
};
```

Then in my template all I'll have to do is this :

```
<select ng-options="$ctrl.options_string" ...></select>
```

But obviously it's not working. Looking at `options_string`, I get something like this :

> obj as obj[name] for obj in $ctrl.options track by obj[url]

where `$ctrl.options` is a binding that contains the list of all the possible options.

Any idea how to do something like this ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure it is a good idea to generate all the string including the keywords, I suggest to generate the Array with label and value instead and loop over the items.

Comment: What do you mean @yazabtahhan ? Also, I was also thinking. Isn't it just wrong to generate it as a string ? Because I know AngularJS will interpret it afterwards.